# Dell XPS 15 9560 Ubuntu Slow boot / WIFI problems

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, boot, laptop, xps

I have problems with my Dell XPS 15 9560 Ubuntu 20.04.

First, the WIFI started to have connection problems. Then reboot started to get slow (minutes instead of seconds). Also when you wanted to log in it took a minute before you could input any text. After that, it was nice and fast.

A few reboots later the WIFI didn't do anything anymore. The laptop was extremely slow. I checked the temps and the CPU was heat throttling.

So I opened the laptop and started cleaning the fans(they were really dirty). Also noticed I got the famous killer wifi switch. After cleaning I booted up again. Still slow boot and no Wifi. I did the DELL Diagnostic (boot option) and it couldn't find any problems. Fans were spinning normally.

So I thought it was the killer wifi adapter. I disabled WIFI in the bios, but still super slow boot. I tried to install an old USB wifi adapter (didn't work). But now after boot, the screen gets darker than normal, and I can not adjust it. Also, I checked the SSD and the benchmarks were good.

I don't mind doing a reinstall and installing a new WIFI chip, but the dimmed screen got me worried. Is this the last minute of the laptop? Or do you think with a new Ubuntu install and WIFI chip it can work properly again?

Comment: Since there are a *number* of issues, I'd suspect major HDD or SSD corruption or a hardware issue. Try running from a Ubuntu Live USB, https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/, and if WiFi works, and the screen is normal brightness, it's an issue with the OS on the drive and/or a dying drive.

Comment: Thanks! I did that and everything seemed to work. So I used Hirens Boot CD to use the SSD Diagnostic tools, and everything was fine with the SSD. I renewed the thermal pasta on the CPU and everything worked. Until I booted. After that I whiped the SSD and reinstalled Ubuntu and it works now properly(still after 20boots). So its fixed. Thanks for your help and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it. However, as a note to others (more than to you), be *exceedingly* careful with thermal paste. There are a number of questions in Superuser about what to do after destroying the CPU by injudicious removal of the heat sink or incorrect application of a thermal compound (some of which may be conductive).